# display avg of the last column on the last row in SQL query

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hello I am having trouble trying to figure out this particular question. using oracle SQL developer.

trying to figure out how a query so that it will display exactly like the below table/picture.

the **last row** **of this query to display word AVERAGE:** and **show the average (of all values in the in the sixth column)** of the percentage above min selling price for all the sales made. and all the remaining column to display "--------"

```
Code      ProductName   Title    ShopID   SalePrice    %SoldAbove Min.SellPrice   
1         Martin        Robot       1        $49000                   15%
2      
3
4
---        ------        ----      ----     AVERAGE:             16.5%
```

below is last row of the output i am looking for. But i have no clue on how to produce the
"--------" in the remaining columns let alone **AVERAGE:** and the average of all the values in the sixth column of the last row.

in summary, the last row of the output should show the average (in the sixth column) of the percentage
sold above the minimum selling price for all the sales.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `ROLLUP`:

```sql
SELECT DECODE( GROUPING( Code ), 1, '----', code ) AS code,
       DECODE( GROUPING( Code ), 1, '----', MAX(col1) ) AS Col1,
       DECODE( GROUPING( Code ), 1, '----', MAX(col2) ) AS Col2,
       DECODE( GROUPING( Code ), 1, 'Average:', MAX(col3) ) AS Col3,
       AVG( value )
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY ROLLUP(Code);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( code, col1, col2, col3, value ) AS
SELECT 1, 'AAA', 1, 'AA1', 15.0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'BBB', 2, 'BB2', 17.5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'CCC', 3, 'CC3', 20.0 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> CODE | COL1 | COL2 | COL3     | AVG(VALUE)
> :--- | :--- | :--- | :------- | ---------:
> 1    | AAA  | 1    | AA1      |         15
> 2    | BBB  | 2    | BB2      |       17.5
> 3    | CCC  | 3    | CC3      |         20
> ---- | ---- | ---- | Average: |       17.5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d3bc8a5f639e803a9723912cfd11c9be)*

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for UNION ALL. A good way to get this sort of result:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT COALESCE(whatever1, '------') whatever1
           COALESCE(whatever2, '------') whatever2,
           COALESCE(whatever3, '------') whatever3, 
           whatever4
      FROM whatever
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, AVG(whatever4) FROM whatever
) r 
ORDER BY whatever1 NULLS LAST
```

The COALESCE function puts your `-----` characters into the output.

You can also investigate `GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP`. It may do what you want.